# Google Drive API access files from Server

Tags: android, python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I want to build an Android Application in which the user gives permission to my server-side script to read their files.

Seems pretty straight-forward, I've made an app where the application can access the user's files.

However, giving access to the server is a lot harder, thanks to OAuth2.0 which has me confused as hell.

Is it even **possible** to build what I want, and if so, how can I achieve this? Links to tutorials are also accepted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the [library](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/index.html) I used at a previous job and it saved me a lot of the hassle in dealing with the Google API directly. Just be sure to follow the authentication part carefully as you need the `.ovpn` file in order to access your drive.